# is there any alternative to easybinder

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to combine database file(.db) to an .exe file so that only one .exe file is visible and the database is attached to it. I found a software "EASYBINDER" to do the job but unfortunately it shows is detected as virus. Is there any alternative software or method for it.

Comment: Can't you create the database when the .exe is started for the first time?

Comment: yes the database is created automatically when the program is run the first time but i was wanting to combine the database for better portability.